# Trying to figure out why this loop prints the wrong list item

Tags: python, list, for-loop

With these loops, I'm comparing if a value from dictList1 is in a range value in dictList2. If it is, then I grab the "sample" value from dictList2 and put it in dictList1. However, in my last *if* statement I'm attempting to handle a scenario where a value from dictList1 is not in dictList2 and then print that value out etc., but what is happening is that it ends up printing the item in the list that is *after* the item that contains the value that is not in dictList2 - aka it's printing the wrong item in dictList1. I have no idea why

```
dictList1 = [
    {
        "name" : "item0",
        "num" : 40,
        },
    {
        "name" : "item1",
        "num" : 20,
    },
]

dictList2 = [{'range':range(1,10),'sample':10},{'range':range(11,25),'sample':20},{'range':range(21,30),'sample':30}]

def func():
    for item in dictList1:
        for item2 in dictList2:
            if item['num'] in item2['range']:
                item['sample'] = item2['sample']
    if item['num'] not in item2['range']:
        print(str(item['num']) + " is not in a range.")
    print(dictList1)

func()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's hard to understand the description of the problem. Could you please show: 1) a *small* example of *exactly* what could be in `dictList1` and `dictList2` beforehand; 2) *exactly* what *should* happen (printed output, as well as the resulting state of the variables); 3) *exactly* what *does* happen, and *how that is different* from the expectation? Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: After the first loop ends, `item` is the last item in `dictList1`

Comment: Also: What does `otherFunc` do? Can you reproduce the problem without that outside processing? Also: I can't understand this part of the description - "if it is then I grab the "sample" value from dictList2 and put it in dictList1". *What part of your code* is supposed to cause that to happen? Where the code says, for example `if item['num'] in item2['range']:`, which `item['num']` do you expect to be used, and why? Did you intend to nest the two `for` loops? Because as shown, they are not nested.

Comment: Looks like an indentation problem. Any possibility That you need a nested loop (Loop inside the loop)?

Comment: hey - I've updated the code in the post. As you can see it prints that "20 is not in range", but actually it is and it successfully pulls the sample value from "dictList2" into "dictList1"

Comment: I suggest debugging your code so gain a deeper insight into what it is doing. The most basic debugging can be done with `print()` statements. For more debugging tips, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the final `if` in your code to print out any `num` values from the first list of dictionaries that don't get matched by any of the ranges in the second list of dictionaries. Your current code isn't doing that because when it runs, it's checking only the last value from each list against each other (even if the `num` matched somewhere else).

Here's what I think you want:

```
for item in dictList1:
    unmatched = True
    for item2 in dictList2:
        if item['num'] in item2['range']:
            item['sample'] = item2['sample']
            unmatched = False
    if unmatched:
        print(str(item['num']) + " is not in a range.")
print(dictList1)
```

This code uses a boolean flag variable `unmatched` to tell the `if` at the end if a match was found in the inner loop or not. If you only wanted to find one match (e.g. because the `range`s in `dictList2` never overlapped), you could use slightly simpler code using `break` and an `else` clause attached to the loop, like this:

```
for item in dictList1:
    for item2 in dictList2:
        if item['num'] in item2['range']:
            item['sample'] = item2['sample']
            break
    else:
        print(str(item['num']) + " is not in a range.")
print(dictList1)
```

This probably won't do what you want though, since you've got overlapping ranges and it will stop the inner loop after the first match is found. The printing logic will be fine, but the in-place modifications to `dictList1` will not be the same.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, ty! - I definitely need to get a better understanding of for loops - what I thought was happening was not what was actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in dictList1:
    item['num'] = otherFunc(item['query'])
# ... other code
```

When that loop finishes, `item` ends up as the final value in `dictList1`.  So all the subsequent references to `item` will use that final value.

Perhaps you meant to indent the other code *underneath* this loop?

Comment: hey - I've updated the code in the post. As you can see it prints that "20 is not in range", but actually it is and it successfully pulls the sample value from "dictList2" into "dictList1"

Comment: Your updated code has the same problem.  The final `if item['num'] not in item2['range']` statement is _not_ inside the for loops, so it uses whatever values of `item` and `item2` that were left over after the loops finished.

Comment: And indeed, the final number in `dictList1` is 20, which is not within the final range (21,30) in `dictList2`.

Comment: indenting or bringing it inside the loop doesn't seem to fix the issue - there definitely seems to be a bigger problem which I don't understand yet.

Comment: Update the code in the question.  Otherwise we have no idea what you've tried.